# Examples of censorship causing economic decline

Tags: economy

I am writing a blog post about knowledge banning, either by state censorship or by self-imposed censorship, like the [US Comics Code Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comics_Code_Authority) of the 20th century.

My focus is moral censorship, driven by cultural and religious taboos, and not military censorship defending state secrets.

Are there any good examples of moral censorship causing a dramatic economic decline on the imposers?

Comment: I doubt you'll find *dramatic* examples. The whole point of decline is that it's slow and at first imperceptible.

Comment: Yes, but it might have a dramatic end point, like losing a war due to scientific inferiority caused by censorship.

Comment: It's rather the opposite.  The decline of a civilization has long been linked, anecdotally, to *less* moral censure and a decline in manners (manners being self, usually-moral censorship).  Of course, excessive *arbitrary* dictates are also counterproductive.  This is an interesting question, but it may be hard to pin it down with science.

Comment: PS:  If *amoral* censorship is bad (it is), then [we are in big trouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Information_Security_Oversight_Office_%28ISOO%29_2011_Annual_Report_to_the_President.pdf&page=12).

Comment: @BrockAdams: Linked by whom?

Comment: APropos, I really wonder what the CCA had against vampires and cannibals...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, IIRC, people like Cato, Mark Twain, Heinlein, Bismark (I think), and Churchill all remarked that declining manners were a sure indicator of a society in collapse. I think Jefferson or Adams might have said this too.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Mind if I convert the incipient discussion into a question?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, go ahead, but I make no promises to attempt to answer it.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Be careful phrasing it. It sounds like a candidate for "Subjective and argumentative" closing.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Well, I tried - http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7795/the-idea-of-moral-censure-leading-to-decline.

Comment: I'd say the Taliban in Afghanistan are a prime example, or Iran under the mullahs, of imposing a strict code of "morality" leading to decline. Of course in both cases that coincided with international isolation because of the brutality and aggressiveness of the regimes both foreign and domestic, but that too was a result of the attitudes/morality of the regimes.

Comment: I'm very skeptical that anyone will be able to connect the dots; if you could, I think it would be a book contract. Although I think it is a fascinating question, I'd support a vote to close unless we can refine the scope to somethign that fits within the guidelines in the FAQ.

Comment: Too broad: requests infinite list rather than a discrete answer.  Poorly formed question as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ottoman suppression of the printing press is sometimes [discussed by economists](http://faculty.fullerton.edu/jrubin/Printing_Ottoman.pdf) as a contributor to that empire's very long and slow decline:

> **The Ottomans regulated the printing press heavily 
>   to prevent the loss it would have caused to the ruler’s net revenue by undermining the legitimacy 
>   provided by religious authorities** . . . Although the Ottomans were by no means alone in suppressing the
>   printing press, they  sustained printing restrictions much longer than
>   any other ruler in Europe. Even after starting to  relax restrictions
>   in 1726, they continued to heavily regulate the operation by granting 
>   permission only to selected individuals, prohibiting publication in
>   religious subjects, and  appointing a committee of scholars to review
>   and proofread contents for accuracy.

These economists consider the economic impact of this three-century ban to be substantial. In some very technical language, they argue:

> **The heavy regulation of the printing press is puzzling because the
>   Ottoman sultans could  have raised the society's taxable surplus and
>   thus their own revenue by allowing it to operate  freely**. The new
>   technology would have raised the surplus directly through its effect
>   on the  market for books and indirectly through positive externalities
>   that would have benefited other  sectors. . . The indirect effects of
>   mass printing on the  aggregate surplus would also have been positive
>   through economic development. As Buringh and van Zanden (2009: 409)
>   have argued, books were "strategic commodities [that were] a  crucial
>   part of the information infrastructure and, in a way, the 'hardware'
>   which stored all ideas."  In the same way, noting the high correlation
>   between reading ability and human capital  formation, **Baten and van
>   Zanden (2008) have recently used per capita book production as a 
>   proxy variable for advanced literacy skills and found a significant
>   relationship between book  production and the onset of modern economic
>   growth in Europe. By promoting mass printing  technologies, the
>   Sultan would have enhanced the production and accumulation of economic
>   ideas that were essential for economic development and surplus
>   generation.**

Obviously, there was more to the Ottoman Decline than the ban on the printing press. Read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historiography_of_the_fall_of_the_Ottoman_Empire#The_decline_theory) if you want a full rundown of theories. But there is no doubt that retarding the dissemination of literacy and scientific progress at the dawn of the modern era was a *bad* economic policy.

---

Source: "[The Political Economy of Mass Printing: 
Legitimacy, Revolt, and Technological Change in the Ottoman Empire.](http://faculty.fullerton.edu/jrubin/Printing_Ottoman.pdf)" 
Metin M. Coşgel, Thomas J. Miceli, and Jared Rubin.

Answer (score 2):

A historical example of "censorship" was the Spanish Inquisition. Spain was a thriving, "progressive" country until the Inquisition took hold, driving out the Jews, and intimidating other "free thinkers." Then Spain began a long decline lasting perhaps four centuries.

Comment: AFAIR the standard explanation of Spanish decline relates to long term secular inflation due to specie supply expansion—a feudal economy choking itself to death on gold.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: The roots of Spain's decline lay in its reliance on gold rather than "enterpreneurship." "Choking itself to death on gold" may have been a consequence (rather than a cause) of the "Inquisition" mindset. I would even argue that the "censoriousness" that began toward the Jews was later extended to the "Amerindians."

Comment: As far as censoriousness you'd need to go back to the Reconquista—so does censoriousness advance certain economies?

Comment: a major cause for that decline was the deforestation of Spain in the effort to build its fleet. This led to changes in precipitation patterns, failing agriculture, industry was geared towards a single product (ships) almost nationwide, etc. etc.

Comment: +1! There is some controversy and healthy scholarly debate about "Spanish decline" (hinted at in the comments here) but overall I heartily agree - this is a prime example. However, note that it took at least a hundred years before the cumulative effects of the decline began to register and be perceived.

Comment: @jwenting: Your comment addresses mine about the "reliance on gold" (deforesting the country to build the fleet).

Comment: I don't think the spanish inquisition have had the effects commonly atributed by the black legend.  Cervantes and St. Terese of Avila lived under the inquisition.  The true cause for the economic shrink of Spain is the massive emigration to America.  To have ultramar posessions was not  profitable enough.

Comment: @Tom Au The spanish inquisition was founded in 1478 by the catholic kings, Cervantes and St. Therese were formed UNDER the inquisition.  Also, the inquisition was present ALSO in America, thus, the emigration had other causes.