# The history of the idea that lack of moral censure leads to decline

Tags: historiography, history-of-ideas

"The decline of a civilization has long been linked, anecdotally, to less moral censure and a decline in manners (manners being self, usually-moral censorship)." (Brock Adams, commenting an [earlier question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/examples-of-censorship-causing-economic-decline#comment15231_7786)).

My question is: what is the historical pedegree of this notion? Brock Adams has suggested "Cato, Mark Twain, Heinlein, Bismark (I think), and Churchill" but I am not sure about Twain. Cato, for certain. Gibbon also naturally comes to mind.

(To clarify my meaning, [J.B. Bury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._B._Bury) had written two books about the history of ideas: "History of the Freedom of Thought (1914)" and "Idea of Progress (1920)"; I am looking for a similar history of the idea of moral decline).

Comment: problem is, one person's morality is another person's hell. Think the Taliban, they're the peak of "decent" behaviour, demanding a total abstinence of any form of entertainment or temptation. Yet you'd hardly call them civilised I hope. Similarly, I don't call the jailing of people for "indecent exposure" civilised, I find the entire concept of "indecent exposure" to be morally wrong and a violation of the fundamental human right to free expression.

Comment: @jwenting: Sure, that's why I am not asking "do loose morals lead to decline?" but rather "who said in history that loose morals lead to decline?" So, your comment answers my question thus: "The Taliban did and jwenting doesn't". :)

Comment: Excellent conversion of a potentially argumentative discussion into a history of ideas question.

Comment: The old blame the young's moral laxity, the young blame the old's inaction.

Comment: I meant to emphasize manners more -- which was mostly what the people I remember were writing/talking about.  This does not include *all* "moral" censure, by a broad definition of the term.  For example, excessive arbitrary dictates -- the kind often associated with "religious persecution" -- would not apply. But I would argue that they where not moral either.

Comment: @BrockAdams: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "manners". Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you are sincere, read Emily Post's books, especially the earlier editions of *Etiquette in Society, in Business, in Politics, and at Home*. ... "Manners" is a pattern of self-imposed behavior (sometimes reinforced by social pressure), whereby one is gracious, tolerant, and forgiving by default.  If/When those behaviors prove to be unwarranted in a particular case, manners can also guide the practitioner unto a more measured/rational response.  But, manners do not mean you must be a wimp or "PC". Decent people spend decades learning manners, it's hard to summarize them in a comment.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Thanks for the clarification. I'm all for manners in this sense (and hopefully, I am sincere about it). But I am not certain that manners have much to do with the decline of societies, would that it were so simple. Also, I find it hard to square Cato with good manners - I don't know if you meant the elder or the younger one, but both were essentially uncouth bigoted brutes (the one naturally, the other more by studied affectation). Sure, they had other redeeming qualities, but of good manners they had proverbially little. On the other hand, I now see how Mark Twain could fit in.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg not really, it doesn't say I don't say that (though I don't, more the reverse), I only say there's no hard and fast definition of "loose morals", rather it depends on context. e.g. some people get angry and insult others for being barefoot in our "civilised moral society", is it ever moral to insult people just because they dress or behave in a way you yourself think is weird, without even knowing the reason those people behave or dress like that?

Comment: @jwenting: But everyone has is definition and a person may state that society is declning because people are doing X without everyone agreeing with him that X is bad. I am interested in the historical provenance of such arguments, irrespective of what you or I or anyone maks of them.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg the historical provenance probably comes down to people across the ages always having looked at the past through rose coloured glasses, and blaming "modern ways" for everything that's wrong. Classic example is people now blaming computer games for everything (or is it cellphones now?), my parents blamed television, my grandparents radio, my great grandparents would have blamed books, etc. etc.

Comment: @jwenting: So it seems we are now in agreement. But I want examples of intellectual trend-setters (to use a modern, rather ugly, term) espousing that view, not just the usual curmudgeoning we all sometimes engage in.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg as everyone does it, you won't get many reports of "trend setters" doing it as it won't be seen as a trend, it's not fashionable :) But look at proposed laws wanting to ban "violent videogames", then go back 25-30 years and look for records trying to ban "violent TV shows", etc. etc.

Comment: Could you revise the title to more closely match the question?  You've asked for an intellectual pedigree, and (inadvertently) spurred a discussion of morality, culture and the Decline & Fall of the Roman Empire. (?? Gibbon's corrollary to Godwin's law?)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Done, thanks for the suggestion! And I loved the corollary.

Comment: You probably mean "the idea that LESS moral censure leads to decline".

Answer (score 4):

Edward Gibbon, in "*the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire*," lists the following reasons (among others):

The five marks of the Roman decaying culture:

1. Concern with displaying affluence instead of building wealth;
2. Obsession with sex and perversions of sex;
3. Art becomes freakish and sensationalistic instead of creative and
   original;
4. Widening disparity between very rich and very poor;
5. Increased demand to live off the state.”

Unfortunately, many of these symptoms are found in America today.

Comment: and none of them explain what really happened, which is permanent civil war draining the country of its resources, until invasion by marauding tribes could no longer be resisted because all the legions were either destroyed, too busy fighting each other, or positioned to defend remote areas where their commanders had set up private fiefdoms rather than where they could provide defense for the empire as a whole.

Comment: @jwenting: Actually, we can't be sure what happened at all. I mean, the bare facts are more or less known but there are a number of very different interpretations one can put on them. I'd cite here the introductory part of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decline_of_the_Roman_Empire#Theories_of_a_fall.2C_decline.2C_transition_and_continuity - but with some trepidation because I actually wrote that bit myself a while ago... :) Still, I think it's a cogent partial summary of the debates on this.

Comment: I view Gibbon as just one more example of the history of the "moral decline" theories that the OQ was talking about. So clearly these ideas were around in the 18th century.